# Error: not found: value lit/when - spark scala

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am using scala, spark, IntelliJ and maven.

I have used below code :

```
val joinCondition = when($"exp.fnal_expr_dt" >= $"exp.nonfnal_expr_dt",
$"exp.manr_cd"===$"score.MANR_CD")

val score = exprDF.as("exp").join(scoreDF.as("score"),joinCondition,"inner")
```

and

```
val score= list.withColumn("scr", lit(0))
```

But when try to build using maven, getting below errors -

> error: not found: value when

and

> error: not found: value lit

For `$` and `===` I have used `import sqlContext.implicits.StringToColumn` and it is working fine. No error occurred at the time of maven build.But for `lit(0)` and `when` what I need to import or is there any other way resolve the issue.

Comment: You need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

Comment: I have answered part of your question. What is the type of list ? is it a DataFrame ?

Comment: @eliasah: Both are Dataframe

Comment: What's the Spark version do you use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's consider the following context :

```
val spark : SparkSession = _ // or val sqlContext: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc) for 1.x
val list: DataFrame = ???
```

To use `when` and `lit`, you'll need to import the proper functions :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}
```

Now you can use them as followed :

```
list.select(when(col("column_name").isNotNull, lit(1)))
```

Now you can use lit also in your code :

```
val score = list.withColumn("scr", lit(0))
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for "import sqlContext.implicits.StringToColumn" 
in the case of  $ and ===